# Burrow integration with MSK Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-msk

I am trying to connect Burrow to AWS MSK Kafka. I keep receiving below message. I am able to connect to MSK from same EC2 instance following [steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/create-topic.html).However Burrow is not able to connect. We need to specify the truststore which I am not able to set it in Burrow. Any help would be appreciated.

```
client has run out of available brokers
```

Answer (score 1):

AWS support ticket helped me solve the issue. My Client to broker was TLS connection, the steps mentioned in AWS refers to PLAINTEXT. Here is what u need to do to make it work.

1. Run the following command to COPY the cacerts file to the current location:

-> cp /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242.b08-0.amzn2.0.1.x86_64/jre/lib/security/cacerts .

**The JVM path might be different for your instance.

Please note the path of this newly created cacerts file by running the pwd command. This path (say P1) will be used in the next steps.

2. Add additional configuration for TLS in the file /home/ec2-user/go/src/github.com/linkedin/Burrow/config/burrow.toml and adding the following details:

===========
[client-profile.test]

client-id="burrow-test"

kafka-version="0.10.0"
tls="mytlsprofile"

[tls.mytlsprofile]

cafile="P1/cacerts"

noverify=true